# ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Tags: python, linux, opensuse, pyenv

I have tried installing Python in pyenv env, but I am getting the error below. I have added openssl to the path variable as openssl is already available, but still it is throwing the same error.

Also, I tried with a separate user (not root). Same error! And I tried to follow the wiki page (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#error-the-python-ssl-extension-was-not-compiled-missing-the-openssl-lib), but for OpenSUSE I can't find much help on google too.

Can someone guide me on how to proceed this further?

```
xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx:~/.pyenv> pyenv install 3.5.2
Downloading Python-3.5.2.tar.xz...
    -> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tar.xz
    Installing Python-3.5.2...
    WARNING: The Python bz2 extension was not compiled. Missing the bzip2 lib?
    WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
    ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
    
    Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
    https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems
    
    
    BUILD FAILED (SLES 12.1 using python-build 20160726)
    
    Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20160801100205.31144
    Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20160801100205.31144.log
    
    Last 10 log lines:
    (cd /home/xxxxx/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/share/man/man1; ln -s python3.5.1 python3.1)
    if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
            case upgrade in \
                    upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
                    install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
            esac; \
             ./python -E -m ensurepip \
                    $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
    fi
    Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 8.1.1 requires SSL/TLS
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python makes use of underlying operating system libraries to support some of its libraries, and it appears you don't have these libraries installed. On Ubuntu you should be able to install them with

```
$ sudo apt-get install bzip2 libreadline6 libreadline6-dev openssl
```

For SUSE 12, as you have pointed out, the command required was

```
zypper -n install openssl libopenssl-devel
```

**EDIT Sep 30, 2023:** Note, however, that unless you are creating virtual images it's poor practice to install required functionality into the system Python.
Instead, use it (or a different Python version you've installed yourself) to create a virtual environment, and install the necessary dependencies in there. That way you aren't cluttering up other projects' environment with unnecessary (and possibly conflicting) dependencies.

Comment: These are already installed. And for the sake of re-installing again it is showing the  'The highest available version is already installed.' for all of the libs. Is there anything i need to do?

Comment: Do you have the *-dev versions to ensure that compilations find the support libraries?

Comment: Yes, i have installed now. zypper -n install openssl libopenssl-devel

Comment: Did this affect the results, or are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 15):

There is an official guide for troubleshooting build problems here https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/common-build-problems

So for openSuse you must first install the dependencies with:

```
zypper in zlib-devel bzip2 libbz2-devel libffi-devel libopenssl-devel \
readline-devel sqlite3 sqlite3-devel xz xz-devel
```

And also for Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \
libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev \
xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl git
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above answer I had to:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python-openssl
```

Answer (score 3):

```sh
sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

helped me

Answer (score 1):

For me nothing from the above worked on Ubuntu 18.04.I had openssl and openssl-dev along with python-openssl.But It worked with openssl1.0-dev so:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssl1.0-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on an OS that has openssl and openssl-devel installed, but are still getting this error because it's version 3, and version 1.1 is not available (e.g. Amazon Linux 2023), I think I may have a workable hack.

Symlinking the openssl pkgconfig file back to openssl11.pc seems to allow the python configure script to find what it needs.  I haven't done any testing of the resulting build yet, but `pyenv install ...` succeeded with no errors.

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl.pc /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl11.pc
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 219 Nov 29 17:40 /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Feb  3 06:51 /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl11.pc -> openssl.pc
$ pyenv install 3.12.1
Downloading Python-3.12.1.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.1/Python-3.12.1.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.12.1...
Installed Python-3.12.1 to /home/ben.abbott-scott/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1
```