# What dependencies should I install in nix-shell in order to compile Python with pyenv?

Tags: pyenv, nixos, nix-shell

I'm trying to compile python with pyenv. I am compiling [for maximum performance](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/plugins/python-build/README.md#building-for-maximum-performance) but it fails due to dependency errors.

These are what I have in my nix-shell:

```
gnumake
libgcc
gcc13
zlib
gdb
openssl
bzip2
ncurses
libffi
readline
pyenv
```

The error:

```
Successfully installed pip-23.2.1 setuptools-65.5.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/amirreza/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/curses/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
WARNING: The Python curses extension was not compiled. Missing the ncurses lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/amirreza/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: /home/amirreza/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: ffi_type_void
WARNING: The Python ctypes extension was not compiled. Missing the libffi lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/amirreza/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 100, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (NixOS 23.11 using python-build 20180424)
```

I have tried it with both a system installed pyenv and pyenv in nix-shell.

Comment: As the error indicates, have you tried checking their Wiki page for [ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#error-the-python-ssl-extension-was-not-compiled-missing-the-openssl-lib)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701203/error-missing-the-openssl-lib-while-trying-to-install-python)

Comment: @GinoMempin this in combination with this [link](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-install-openssl-to-compile-against/1249) solved open ssl
but still it errors with thesse libraries (tho python did compile): ncurses, libffi, readline, sqlite3, Tk toolkit, lzma

Comment: *update:
adding sqlite, xz, lzma and tk to the packages
sqlite and lzma got solved but the rest are still erroring
these packages are not built in result: ctypes, curses, tkinter, readline